# Does Saiku use Mondrian 4?

Tags: pentaho, mondrian, saiku

I'm using Saiku in our project and reading the documentation I noticed that it's supposed to use Mondrian 4.

Is that right? Is Saiku creating the SQL queries by using Mondrian 4?
If that's true, how is it possible that it reads the properties (pentaho-solutions/system/mondrian/mondrian.properties) for Mondrian 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question...

GlennS is right in stand-alone Saiku using Mondrian 4 but it was not the case when using Pentaho Business Analytics Platform.
There is now a new plugin in the marketplace that allows you to use Mondrian 4 also in the CE edition.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the latest version of Saiku does use Mondrian 4, based on the following (run from the saiku-server directory).

```
$ find . -name mondrian*
./tomcat/webapps/saiku/WEB-INF/classes/mondrian.properties
./tomcat/webapps/saiku/WEB-INF/lib/mondrian-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Note that this is using the stand-alone Saiku, not via Pentaho.